# Create a launchpad application in windows

Tags: c#, wpf

i am trying to build an application in windows like the one in mac OS X called "launchpad" i have a week searching how to do this and i found that WPF could be a great tool, but i am not sure if it is the best way, can someone tell me what should i use and a little help to begin?
thank you.
For those who dont know about mac OS X, launchpad is an application that shows all the applications installed on the computer a cross all the monitor

Comment: Are you referring to *this* Launchpad? http://www.apple.com/macosx/whats-new/launchpad.html

Comment: yes, i want to make that in windows

Comment: WPF does a lot but I think you are going to need to go C++ with calls to DirectX to get something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the reference you provided at [launchpad](http://www.apple.com/macosx/whats-new/launchpad.html), a WPF application would most likely have something like this as a starting point...

```
<Grid>
    <Image Source="galaxy.jpg" Stretch="Fill"/>
    <DockPanel>
        <UniformGrid DockPanel.Dock="Top" Rows="5" Columns="8">
            <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" 
                             Style="{StaticResource PictureButtonStyle}" 
                             Content="{Binding LaunchItem}"/>     
                   .......           
        </UniformGrid>
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <!-- recently used icons go here-->
        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

The grid background has an image of a galaxy, and superimposed upon the image, there's a DockPanel.  In the DockPanel, there's a UniformGrid.  Each cell of the UniformGrid holds a Launch target.

The individual Launch targets would have to be configured such that they contained the right icon and enough information to launch the appropriate program.

The MRU list (Most Recently Used) icons would be replicated in the Stack Panel anchored to the bottom of the DockPanel.

Comment: Thank you very much, it is a useful code, but i can not run it because there is a mistake at this line:
Style="{StaticResource PictureButtonStyle}"
any idea?

Comment: This bit of Xaml refers to something you must write in order to achieve the UI you are developing.  For the moment, you can delete 'Style={StaticResource PictureButtonStyle}' and the code should work, but you will see only the default WPF buttons.  The intent here was to show an overall WPF approach.  For help with how the buttons should be templated, please raise another question.